# How to plot in rshiny depending on the columns I choose

Tags: r, shiny

I have made a shiny app which takes in any data and shows column names depending on the data.

```
c1 <- rnorm(10,0,1)
c2 <- c(rep("txA",5),rep("txB",5))
c3 <- c(1:4,1:4,1:2)
c4 <- rep(LETTERS[1:5],2)
mydata <- data.frame(c1,c2,c3,c4)

ui <- fluidPage(
fileInput(inputId = "file",
        label = "import file"),
tableOutput("tb"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
uiOutput(outputId = "aa")
),
mainPanel(textOutput("a"),
          verbatimTextOutput("info"),
          verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
          plotOutput("plot", click = "plot_click")
)
          )
)


server <- function(input,output) {



output$aa <- renderUI({
validate(need(input$file != "", ""))
mydata <- read.csv(input$file$datapath)
selectInput(inputId = "aa", #can be any name?
            label="Select:",
            choices = colnames(mydata))
})

output$tb <- renderTable({
data <- input$file
if (is.null(data))return()
read.table(data$datapath,sep=",")
})

output$summary <- renderPrint({
summary(mydata)
})

output$plot <- renderPlot({
plot(mydata)
})

output$info <- renderText({
paste0("x=", input$plot_click$x, "\ny=", input$plot_click$y)
})


}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

If I run this I get the following:

[image: the following]

I am trying to make a shiny app which shows a basic plot depending on the columns that I choose. How would I do this?

Comment: Hello Seung, what is a "basic plot"?

Comment: Hi Pascallv, sorry about the vagueness. I was referring to the plot that I posted above except that I wanted to make a plot that shows only one plot at a time instead of the whole variables like above depending on the variables I choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do, make sure to uncomment the file input

```
library(shiny)

c1 <- rnorm(10,0,1)
c2 <- c(rep("txA",5),rep("txB",5))
c3 <- c(1:4,1:4,1:2)
c4 <- rep(LETTERS[1:5],2)
mydata <- data.frame(c1,c2,c3,c4)


ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput(inputId = "file",
            label = "import file"),
  tableOutput("tb"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput(outputId = "aa")
    ),
    mainPanel(textOutput("a"),
              verbatimTextOutput("info"),
              verbatimTextOutput("summary"),
              plotOutput("plot", click = "plot_click")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output) {

  output$aa <- renderUI({
    #validate(need(input$file != "", ""))
    #mydata <- read.csv(input$file$datapath)

    ## Since your  output$aa already has name aa you cant use it twice!
    selectInput(inputId = "aa2", #can be any name?
                label="Select:",
                choices = colnames(mydata))
  })

  output$tb <- renderTable({
    data <- input$file
    if (is.null(data))return()
    read.table(data$datapath,sep=",")
  })

  mysubsetdata <- eventReactive(input$aa2,{
    mydata[[input$aa2]]
  })


  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(mysubsetdata())
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plot(mysubsetdata())
  })

  output$info <- renderText({
    paste0("x=", input$plot_click$x, "\ny=", input$plot_click$y)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

[image]

- Added `eventReactive` to listen to `selectInput`
- All widgets must have unique id so you cannot use `aa` twice, one for renderui and one for selectInput

Comment: So eventReactive was the key point. Thank you so much!! In the meanwhile, I have been thinking of a more advanced app which are as follows: There are two drop down menus. One for X axis and one for Y axis having all the columns of my data, respectively . So I get to choose from the two dropdown menus which will give me more options for plotting my data. How would I code this? Thanks again!

Comment: 1) if this answers your question then please accept the answer
2) create a separate question for your other app

Comment: I just accepted your answer. Since I am a new user here I wasn't aware of the accepting system. Thank you again. I will post my question at a separate page.